# How to save a mailitem to outlook from file

Tags: c#, .net, file, outlook

Currently I am writing a console application that deleetes all existing mails and has to get new ones from a .msg file (So it resets the outlook mails).
I want to copy import files from a .msg file to the Outlook inbox, however I can't seem to find a proper way of doing so.

I've tried different methods i found here and in the internet and the one that "works" the most ist by mail.move(inbox). This adds the mail to the inbox, but also throws an Exception - System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot move the items.', which I cannot get rid of.

```
private static void FillInbox(NameSpace ns)
    {
        MAPIFolder inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        MailItem mail = ns.OpenSharedItem($@"W:\CopyThis.msg");
        mail.Move(inbox);
     }
```

Can you help me get a better way of doing this? One that does not throw an Exception?

Comment: You might want to look into Exchange Web Services instead of Outlook interop. That way you can work with your inbox without depending on a single client/computer. Perhaps this helps you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-import-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) method of the Application class which creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item. In my tests against Outlook 2010 and upper, I tried to pass the path to a `.msg` file to the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method and it worked like a charm. So, you can use `.msg` and `.oft` files as templates.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// ...
private void CreateItemBasedOnTemplate(Outlook.Application Application)
{
    Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder containerFolder = null;
    Outlook.MailItem item = null;
    Outlook.MailItem movedItem = null;
    try
    {
        ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        containerFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        item = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(@"D:\MyTemplate.msg", containerFolder) 
            as Outlook.MailItem;
        // the item was created in the Drafts folder regardless
        // that is why we move it to the Inbox folder
        movedItem = item.Move(containerFolder) as Outlook.MailItem;
        movedItem.Save();
        movedItem.Display();
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        if (ex.ErrorCode == -2147287038)
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
               "Can't find the template...");
        else
           System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
               "An error was occurred when creating a new item from template...");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (movedItem != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(movedItem);
        if (item != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
        if (containerFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(containerFolder);
        if (ns != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
    }
}
```

You may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article helpful.

Comment: Actually read some of your articles on add-in-express just before posting here.
Thanks for the fast help, really works like a charm!

Comment: Do not use Application.CreateItemFromTemplate - it always creates the item in the unsent state and skips the sender related properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` - it returns `MailItem` object that you can then move to any folder using `MailItem.Move` or `MailItem.Copy / MalItem.Move`.

Unlike `OpenSharedItem.CreateItemFromTemplate` (which always creates the item in the unsent state and skips the sender related properties), `Namespace.OpenSharedItem` makes all propertiss available

Comment: Good objection. However those two disadvantages are irrelevant to me. Also i didn't get .OpenSharedItem to work without an exception. So I'll stick with .CreateItemFromTemplate for now.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: The one I added in my post. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Cannot move the items.'

Comment: Did you use just Move? Or Copy, and then Move on the new item returned by Copy?

Comment: As far as I remember i tried both, may have messed something up thouh.